# Alert handling is not working in Chrome v62 and above using selenium and python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browserstack

I am trying to accept an alert using python-selenium in Chrome v62 to v66.
I have checked the compatibilies of the driver and selenium, there seems to be no issues in them. The exception occurs in local as well as in browserstack.

Code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present) 
Alert(driver).accpet()
currentURL= driver.current_url
```

Error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.170)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544337 (8c0344a12e552148c185f7d5117db1f28d6c9e85),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

I have tried waiting for the alert and then switch and accept it also. The alert is present but `EC.alert_is_present` returns false.

The same code works as expected in Chrome v61 and below.

Comment: Relevant code for `trying to accept an alert`?

Comment: @DebanjanB Tried accepting the alert with all possible approaches `Alert(driver).accept()` , `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()`

Comment: You still haven't shown us your code trials. `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present)` would never raise `UnexpectedAlertPresentException`

Comment: After accepting the alert, I perform other actions on the webpage. These throw `UnexpectedAlertPresentException`, since the accept alert did not work and the alert remains open.

Comment: @Maria Could you please update your question with code snippet you are using and any other code samples you have tried? I can confirm that browser.switch_to.alert.accept() works well on local setup as well as browserstack

Comment: @BountyHunter Have you tried accepting alerts in Chrome latest versions specifically v62 and above. They are failing only in these versions. After accepting the alert, I get the current url of the page. This statement throws `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` as the alert remains open